# Ignoring Route Parameters in Laravel like in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've been working with Lumen, and I've noticed a convenient feature where I can ignore some route parameters, and the parameter will automatically match the name of the argument. However, in Laravel, it seems like this option is not available by default.

eg:

```
Route::get('{category_id}/system/batches/{batch_id}', 'CirculyDb\Settings\BatchSettingController@show');

// controlloer method, category_id can be ignored  
public function show($batch_id): JsonResponse
```

Is there a way to achieve similar behavior in Laravel, where I can ignore specific route parameters and have them automatically match the corresponding argument name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible because the routing code is completely different.

You can achieve something similar to what you need by using the route method on the request:

```
Route::get('{category_id}/system/batches/{batch_id}', 'CirculyDb\Settings\BatchSettingController@show');

// controller method, category_id can be ignored  
public function show(): JsonResponse {
    request()->route('batch_id');
}
```

As an aside Lumen uses `Container::call` to call controller methods which will do dependency injection but also match named parameters, while laravel does a simple method invocation, so presumably if you implement your own `ControllerDispatcher` you can possibly emulate this behaviour. Original source for that is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php). I briefly tried but it's a bit too complex to do with reasonable effort.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, you can achieve a behavior similar to Lumen by using optional parameters in your routes. The official documentation provides guidance on [how to do this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters). Let's say you want to make the `category_id` parameter optional and have it automatically match the argument name. Here's how you can achieve that:

```php
Route::get('/{category_id?}/system/batches/{batch_id}', 'CirculyDb\Settings\BatchSettingController@show');

// Controller method with an optional parameter
public function show($batch_id, $category_id = null): JsonResponse
{
    // Your controller logic here
}
```

In this example, we've made `category_id` an optional parameter by adding a `?` after its name in the route definition. The controller method includes the optional parameter `$category_id` with a default value of `null`, which allows it to match the argument name and automatically set it to null if `category_id` is not present in the URI. This way, you can achieve the desired behavior in Laravel, similar to what you experienced in Lumen.

Comment: It does not solve my problem, Laravel cares about the order of the arguments, so category_id value will be always in the first argument and batch_id second, on lumen order does not matter also I can literraly omit a variable from the method declaration example if I define public function show($batch_id) only I will always get the value of batch_id no matter what other variables are into the URL